# Channels not available

Tags: c#, glue42

I lack the channels dropdown in my sticky windows.

I set `glueWindowOptions.WithChannelSupport(true);` as per the [documentation](https://docs.glue42.com/g4e/net-channels/index.html#channels-overview).

My windows still lack the dropdown though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you didn't register the `glueWindowOptions` object to the `glue` object?

Here is a sample code that initializes a WPF application as a Glue42 one, having channels enabled:

```
        Glue42 glue = new Glue42();
        glue.Initialize("DotNetApp");

        // Initialize Window Stickiness and read from config:
        var swOptions = glue.GlueWindows?.GetStartupOptions() ?? new GlueWindowOptions();
        swOptions.WithChannelSupport(true);
        glue.GlueWindows?.RegisterWindow(this, swOptions);
```

Please note the final line, you need to register the `swOptions` object (in your case, the `glueWindowOptions` one) via the `RegisterWindow` method.

Comment: Yes, that was it!
Do I need the `glue.GlueWindows?.GetStartupOptions() ??` check?

Comment: Sorry, it is necessary. You only need it if you want to attempt reading the configuration from a JSON file first.